# Flutter web 'Uncaught MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Query#get on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_firestore)'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this Cloud Firestore error only when running the web app from its release build; it works fine in the simulator though. Here is the call that triggers that:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
await db.collection('orders').where('publicOrderId', isEqualTo: orderNumber).get().then((querySnapshot) async { // Error happens here
  if(querySnapshot.docs != null){
    // Logic
    }
});
```

The error thrown happens at the `.get()` part of the asynchronous function.

I've added the required scripts in index.html and initialized firebase in main.dart.

Comment: Try to stop the emulator and run `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get` then run the emulator again this alone solves many issues. If not fixed with this then please provide more details to narrow down the issue's root cause.

Comment: The issue is not the emulator; it works great in the emulator, but when I build with `flutter build web` and use that version, I get the error mentioned above

Comment: can you share more information like how you set up the flutterfire sdk how you initialize the firebase sdk and where you are using this method info like this helps to identify the correct issue.

Comment: I set up exactly as instructed here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web

Comment: According to this [documentations](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web#:~:text=For%20more%20information%20on%20setting%20Firebase%20up%20for%20the%20web%2C%20view%20the%20official%20documentation.) If you want to use Firebase sdk with the web then you should use [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Comment: @RohitKharche yes that's the link I meant to copy. I used the official documentation.

Comment: I mean to say for web you are better off using firebase web sdk rather than FlutterFire SDK. If you want to use FlutterFire SDK then you should initialize it with [using the CLI](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#using-the-flutterfire-cli)